# Throw exception or return a crazy value when input is bad, but might be common?

Tags: java, exception, null

I have a class that analyzes and interprets GPS strings. The incoming strings are formatted in a very specific way (15 comma separated strings/values). Right now, if I receive a string that is not expected (like if it doesn't have 14 commas), I am throwing an IllegalArgumentException. This is for the cases when the incoming string is truly broken and this event should rarely, if ever happen.

*However*, if my GPS unit has not connected to the satellite yet, I will receive blank values between the commas. How can I return something that tells the user "The GPS isn't turned on yet," **without** returning Null? In my particular case, returning Null is something that is already needed. I thought of returning some insane value that can be checked against, but this seems like really sloppy program design to me. What would a good method for a situation like this be?

Comment: This question should probably be moved, as it relates more to design (a "why do I" question) rather than a specific technical issue (a "how do I" question). That having been said, are you really technically tied to your current use of the null value? Either way, you're going to have to provide some code, because as stated, the question is rather general.

Comment: I am tied to Null. Not by my own code, but because my class implements Java's callable which can return Null when the .poll() method is used.

Comment: Throw a GpsNotTurnedOnException.